# Can I use lambda expression itself when I need its output as input?

Tags: c#, lambda

In other words, can these lines be combined?

```cs
Func<int, int> square = x => x * x;
Console.WriteLine(square(5));
```

There is no recursion here - I'm not looking for [Y combinator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31819718/using-the-y-combinator-in-c-sharp), but rather just immediately using the function I defined.

I tried something like this - but could not get around syntax errors

```cs
Console.WriteLine(
  // defining the function inline 
  (new Func<List<int>, string>(list) => string.Join(",", list))
      (new List<int>{1,2,3}) // immediately passing the parameter
);
```

Comment: These code blocks don't do the same thing. Unclear what your question is. Yes, C# supports anonymous functions... Yes, you can pass arguments to anonymous functions. Yes, you can print the result of calling an anonymous function.

Comment: Also, [join strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610431/string-join-on-a-listint-or-other-type) with a function, not a manual loop

Comment: it was just an example for formatting

Comment: @James please review my edit and updated duplicate - I think I totally misunderstood what you were looking for based on the title... and example actually made sense. I put (slightly shortened) version back... I believe you are after IIFE.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks. I had some misplaced parentheses